# Pass enum to Blazor component's parameter

Tags: generics, enums, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Razor component that needs an enum as a parameter. I've read that you are supposed to use `@typeparam` to pass in a generic type, but when I try it with a variable name of `EnumType`, I'm getting an error of the following every time I type `EnumType`

> The type or namespace name `EnumType` could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

The code looks roughly like:

```cs
@typeparam TEnum


@foreach (EnumType flag in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType)))
    {
        if (((EnumType)Old).HasFlag(flag))
        {
            if (((EnumType)New).HasFlag(flag))
            {
                <li>@EnumExtensions.GetEnumDisplayName(flag)</li>
            }
            else
            {
                <li class="deleted-li">@EnumExtensions.GetEnumDisplayName(flag)</li>
            }

        }
    }

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public TEnum EnumType { get; set; }
    //          ^ only time I dont get the error

    [Parameter]
    public int Old { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int New { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: I went for a break and came back to look at my code and realized it made no sense. I have since updated it to resemble:

```cs
@typeparam TEnum

@foreach (Enum flag in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
    {
        if (((Enum)Convert.ChangeType(Old, typeof(TEnum))).HasFlag(flag))
        {
            if (((Enum)Convert.ChangeType(New, typeof(TEnum))).HasFlag(flag))
            {
                <li>@EnumExtensions.GetEnumDisplayName(flag)</li>
            }
            else
            {
                <li class="deleted-li">
                    @EnumExtensions.GetEnumDisplayName(flag) 
                 </li>
            }

        }
    }
@code{
    [Parameter]
    public int Old { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public int New { get; set; }
}
```

I am now getting an error on `((Enum)Convert.ChangeType(Old, typeof(TEnum))` saying:

> Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'DataAccessLibrary.Enums.TimelineinfoEnums+MisconductEnum'.

Comment: Try code behind with `public partial class YourComponent<TEnum> : ComponentBase where TEnum : Enum`

Comment: `((TEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), Old))`

Comment: Thanks Brian, ```Enum.ToObject```works. I have to cast it to ```Enum``` instead of ```TEnum``` because ```TEnum``` doesnt contain a definition for ```.HasFlag()```

Comment: With the code behind approach it would as it has a Enum constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You need set value for object `EnumType` at lifecycle `OnInitialized(){ ... }` or `OnInitializedAsync(){ ... }`.

Reference document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Yes, I would have needed to do that if I was going to properly use that variable, but since I only needed the type, not the variable, I never needed ```EnumType``` to begin with. I have updated the question to better reflect what I should have done and the issue I now face.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this issue. In your code declare a variable of a type (enum) you need, and then

```
<TargerComponent ParameterThatNeesdEnum="@YourTypedVariable">
```